# Clean URLs - .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, parameters

Clean URLs works only on index.php but not on the other pages (explore and top).
The parameter I want to "clean" is 'genre' (for example: genre=pop).  This is the website:[swiftlymusic.com](http://swiftlymusic.com) and is hosted on a "1&1(1and1 oneandone)" server.
.htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /04.html

RewriteBase /


RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^log$ logs [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ?genre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ ?genre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^explore/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ explore.php?genre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^top/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ top.php?genre=$1 [L]

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-ordering so that the "explore.php" and "top.php" lines are above the general line? Also, you can use '?' instead of repeating the line twice: once with, once without the forward slash.

```
RewriteRule ^explore/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/?$ explore\.php?genre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^top/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/?$ top\.php?genre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ?genre=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The only other thing I can see is escaping the . with `\.`, see my edited answer.

Comment: Still, no change, I added near the genre nav-bar for you to see the results of the full url.

Comment: Ahh, you need to escape the hyphen with a `\-`, see updated code. Try that!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
Options -Multiviews
ErrorDocument 404 /04.html

RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^log$ logs [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ ?genre=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/$ ?genre=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#explore & top and any other can be use by this 1 rule
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([\w-]+)$ $1.php?genre=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: As you can see swiftlymusic.com/pop works and the genre navigation bar shows pop but swiftlymusic.com/explore/pop doesn't work - the genre navigation shows 'all'.